# Lazy Initializations ignored in Spring Data JPA when using @WebAppConfiguration instead of @SpringBootTest in a ControllerTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am using the following model:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private List<Role> roles;

   (...)
}

@Entity
public class Role {

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<User> users;

    (...)
}
```

leading to following repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Then a Controller such as:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public void test(@RequestParam final String u) {
        if(!this.userRepository.findByUsername(u).getRoles().get(0).getUsers().get(0).getRoles().get(0).getName().equals("Role1")) throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}
```

Application is vanilla, does not use any Transaction related annotation (but main is annotated with @SpringBootApplication).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and I am only using a single property in application.properties: `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false`

The test goes like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration @ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/test").param("u", "user1")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Then my issue is that When debugging looks like all the entity diagram is fully eagerly fetched, and test returns successfully, because controller did not fail.

I know JPA repositories methods use a transaction, but as far as as I know, a long as we don't wrap them on a higher level transaction, it should finish after the method ends. How is it possible then that I don't get LazyInitializatioExceptions when trying to access roler or user -> role -> users ??  Is this expected behavior?

This is what Eclipse debugger shows when displaying the users within the roles of a user, for what is worth:

[image]

Hibernate logging shows how it eagerly fetches the relationships when finding a user:

```
12:47:24.890 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer - Loading collection:  ..domain.User.roles
12:47:24.937 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl - Found row of collection: [User.roles#1002]
12:47:24.953 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [...domain.Role#5]
12:47:24.953 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [...domain.Role#5]
12:47:24.953 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext - 1 collections were found in result set for role: ...domain.User.roles
12:47:24.968 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext - Collection fully initialized: [...domain.User.roles#1002]
12:47:24.968 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext - 1 collections initialized for role: ....domain.User.roles
12:47:24.968 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
12:47:24.968 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer - Done loading collection
```

.

**EDIT**: I discovered that if I change the `@WebAppConfiguration` line on the `ControllerTest` by the modern `@SpringBootTest`, I got the `LazyInitializationException`. Why does `@WebAppConfiguration` old way ignoring lazy fetchings?

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot by default registers `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` to apply the Open EntityManager in View pattern, to **allow for lazy loading in web views**. If you do not want this behavior, you should set `spring.jpa.open-in-view` to false in your `application.properties`.

**EDIT:** (*after edit question*)

indeed you should have a **LazyInitializationException**. My guess is that in your test the `Session` is still open?

if you test with `@SpringBootTest` you will get a `LazyInitializationException`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class LazyLoadingExceptionTest {

   @Autowired UserRepository userRepository;

   @Test(expected=LazyInitializationException.class)
   public void showRolesTest() {
     User whimusical =  userRepository.findByUsername("Whimusical");
     System.err.println(whimusical.getRoles());
   }

}
```

but if you test with `@DataJpaTest` you won't get an Exception

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @DataJpaTest
 public class NoLazyLoadingExceptionTest {

   @Autowired UserRepository userRepository;

   @Test
   public void showRolesTest() {
      User whimusical =  userRepository.findByUsername("Whimusical");;
      System.err.println(whimusical.getRoles());
   }
}
```

an other way to trigger a **LazyInitializationException**

override the `toString()` of `User`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return username + " with roles: " + roles;
}
```

and startup the application with this `Component`

```
@Component
public class DataSetup implements CommandLineRunner{

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    Role role = new Role();
    role.setName("user");
    roles.add(roleRepository.save(role));

    User whimusical = new User();
    whimusical.setUsername("Whimusical");
    whimusical = userRepository.save(whimusical);

    whimusical.setRoles(roles);
    whimusical = userRepository.save(whimusical);

    userRepository.findAll().forEach(System.err::println);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But does not seem to be that, still eager fetching with the property. I am not using views at least explictly, just executing the controller through a test and debugging the User when the call to repository is made

Comment: I found some time to bisect the code until I refactored the example into minimal expression and most Boot convention. Last block summarizes a very important finding that narrow downs a lot the scope of the issue